# RecyclerView to dismiss Item with SQLite database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have implemented `RecyclerView` with `SQLite` Database.when i swipe to dismiss, i fetch data from Database and call adapter but it does not work normally, it blinks all the RecyclerView item.can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Post the code you tried

Comment: in refresh method i have created Recylerview adapter and call that adapter within that method.

Comment: when i swipe item it  calls refresh method that contain adapter class and adapter calling like below

Comment: ArrayList<WiFiSchedulerDTO> wifiSchedulerList = wifiSDB.getWifiSchedulerData(deviceID);


        WiFiSchedulerAdapter wifischeduledadapter = new WiFiSchedulerAdapter(WiFiSchedularActivity.this,mContext, wifiSchedulerList);
        scheduler_wifi_list.setAdapter(wifischeduledadapter);
        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SceneItemTouchHelperCallback(wifischeduledadapter);
        mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(scheduler_wifi_list);
        scheduler_wifi_list.scrollToPosition(index);

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using notifydatasetchanged() method, which will recreate all the recycler views( rows ) again. Thats why you are seeing a blink.  Instead you can use notifydataItemChanged(position) or notifydataItemremoved(position)

Comment: yes ofCourse there must be a solution using notifydataitemremoved(pos) but it didnt work. and also i can not get updated data from databasae

Comment: Can you post your ItemTouchHelper.Callback code@PrakashBamaniya